# How can I store a copied google document element?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

My code currently searches for a predefined start tag in google document, and locates a corresponding ending tag. The position of the tags is retained in a variable.

Next the code runs through and copies all of the elements between the tags into a second google document. This works as expected.

However, the data held in the source document has grown to be 100s of pages.  Therefore the script searching for the tags takes a few more seconds than expected. This increases the time it takes to find the tags and copy the elements between them.

My solution to this is to have a master script that picks up the elements once and stores them in something like Firebase or Firestore. Then I can access the elements directly from the DB. I have tried several approaches to store Google document elements.

This is how I get the elements.

```
  var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy(); // Gets Paragraph etc.
```

My attempts include.

- Store the element in an array and then iterate the array - works fine within 
  the same run time.
- Store the element in the document cache - does not work.
- Try to store the element as a blob - don't know how to do correctly.
- Stringify the element and save in document cache - does not work.

Has anybody tried saving Google document elements for use a later date?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google Document elements don't have a representation that can be used outside of Apps Script environment. I suggest using other, smaller, documents to store the elements you'll need later. A script can create documents as needed ([up to 250 per day](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)) and access them by their IDs later. The IDs are strings; they can be associated with some keys according to which you located those elements, and this information can be JSON stringified and stored in Script Properties.

Since there is no `appendElement` method, it seems one has to identify elements by type first, and then append to the target (and not every type is supported by append methods).

```
function storeElements() {
  var elements = ... // your array of elements

  var storage = DocumentApp.create("storage"); // if new is needed
  var body = storage.getBody();
  for (var i in elements) {
    switch (selected[i].getType()) {
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE:
        body.appendImage(elements[i]); break;
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        body.appendListItem(elements[i]); break;
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        body.appendParagraph(elements[i]); break;
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        body.appendTable(elements[i]); break;
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE:
        body.appendHorizontalRule(); break;
        case DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK:
        body.appendPageBreak(); break;
    }
  }
  // store storage.getId(); in ScriptProperties
}
```